# Load/stress testing

Tags: javascript, testing, web-applications, load, mean

I am developing some apis using mean stack. I application that will use these api will have 100 of users at a moment. So haw can I make assure that my api can take a load of 100 requests per second and still give quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [BlazeMeter](https://blazemeter.com/) that can simulate 50 users on a free plan.